# Why can the "Available Balance" and "Deposit / Withdraw" fields conflict?

Tags: wallets

I have an asset with a value in the "Available Balance" field while the  "Deposit / Withdraw" field contains "Not Available"? Why the difference and is there a way to cash out the asset?